# function modify extern variables

Tags: c, extern

My program is compiled with any error but it doesn't work(Segmentation fault). what is the mistake?

a.h

```
extern int k;
extern int j;
char funk(char *str[], int i);
```

a.c

```
#include "a.h"

int k=0;
int j=0;
char funk(char *str[], int i) {
    if (str[k][j] == '\0' && k < i) {
        k++;
        j = 0;
    }

    return str[k][j++];
}
```

b.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char c;
    while (c = funk(argv, argc))
        printf("%c", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't tell me that: `a.h`, `a.c` and `b.c` are your file names? Also did you lost your `main()` function on the way to stackoverflow?

Comment: `k < i` -- `k` ends up being *equal* to `i`, which points out of the array.

Comment: Hi @hrlinc, if any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading out of bounds. Calling func() in a loop ensures that you will eventually read out of bounds, when `k==i` here: `str[k][j] == '\0'`

Do the check `k < i` first.

Comment: thanks but not work! when I remove j=0 in funk program works. but it just print argv[0].

Answer (score 1):

This is because `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be *null pointer*, that you are dereferencing within last iteration.

From N1570 (C11) `5.1.2.2.1/2` *Program startup*:

> `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.

As by @2501's answer the simplest remedy to this issue would be to replace order of `&&` operands.